# Can't find records in Waterline by date/time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, mean-stack, waterline

how compare a datetime in sails.js Model? here it is what i did but without luck.

```
var _date = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS') + 'Z';
Game.find({
    where:{
        active: true,
        start: {
            '>=' : _date
        }
    },
    limit: 1,
    sort: 'start asc'
}, function(err, game) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
    console.log('Game OBJ' + game.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The `datetime` type is transformed into an actual Javascript date in Waterline (the Sails ORM).  So it needs to be compared against a date object, not a string.  You can keep your code exactly as it is, but change the first line to:

```
var _date = new Date(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS') + 'Z');
```

Then your query should find all `Game`s that start in the future.

Of course since your code is just returning current date, you don't really need `moment` at all:

```
var _date = new Date();
```

will work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
var _date = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS') + 'Z';
```

you need to convert above string variable to date variable using below line

```
var tempDate = new Date(_date);
```

Now use $gte instead of '>='

```
Game.find({
    where:{
        active: true,
        start: {
            $gte : tempDate 
        }
    },
    limit: 1,
    sort: 'start asc'
}, function(err, game) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
    console.log('Game OBJ' + game.toString());
});
```

You can also use $gt, $lt, $lte.